# Making a Shaping Drawing+Page Layout Application in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

What would be the feasibility of a creating a page layout/shape drawing, with zooming, saving to database application in silverlight?

Does anyone know where I could find some good learning material on the classes/concepts I would need to know?

I think this would be a fun project.

Thanks in Advance.

Michael

Answer (score 0):

This is a good place to start...  http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/

Generally though Silverlight apps are not meant to talk directly to a database for that you may want to think about using WPF.